# Commands binding troubles on Windows 8 (Release Preview)

Tags: wpf, windows-8, command, .net-4.5

Recently I got chance to play a little bit with Windows 8 Release Preview (Build 8400 to be specific). My aim was to investigate bugs which appeared in our product (WPF application) only under Windows 8. The bugs looked very simple - few buttons were disabled when they shouldn't. It looked easy to fix but I decided to find the root cause.

It turned out that when a control bound to a command receives `CanExecuteChanged` notification it doesn't requery command's `CanExecute` method if sender is not the same command. This is a bit of a problem in a situation when command performs some operation on a model and it's ability to execute depends on model's state. For example, imagine you have a model:

```
class MyModel
  {
    public void ChangeModel(bool makeValidForCommand)
    {
      Valid = makeValidForCommand;

      if (ModelChanged != null)
        ModelChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    public bool Valid { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler ModelChanged;
  }
```

And a command:

```
class MyCommand : ICommand
  {
    public MyCommand(MyModel model)
    {
      _model = model;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return _model.Valid;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
      add { _model.ModelChanged += value; }
      remove { _model.ModelChanged -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) { }

    private MyModel _model;
  }
```

Unfortunately, this won't work on Windows 8 - the button bound to the command will stay improperly disabled (or enabled) after the model changed state. It works perfectly well on Windows 7 though!

The command can be rewritten like this:

```
class MyCommand : ICommand
  {
    public MyCommand(MyModel model)
    {
      _model = model;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return _model.Valid;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
      add
      {
        _canExecuteChanged += value;
        _model.ModelChanged -= _modelChanged;
        _model.ModelChanged += _modelChanged;
      }

      remove
      {
        _canExecuteChanged -= value;
        _model.ModelChanged -= _modelChanged;
      }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
    }

    private void _modelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (_canExecuteChanged != null)
        _canExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    private event EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;
    private MyModel _model;
  }
```

Now sender is the command itself, and everything is fine. Another option is to use `CommandManager` and its `RequerySuggested` event:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
      add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
      remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

And again it works! Hm, now I'm completely puzzled. Sender is not the command - it's null, but if I try to send my own event with null sender it doesn't work again.

Did anyone faced the same? Is it such a strange way of optimization on new Windows? Honestly it looks more like a bug.

Comment: That's weird... WPF is implemented in the .NET framework, not in Windows, so it shouldn't matter which Windows version you're using. Which version of .NET did you use on Windows 8 ?

Comment: Indeed, but I assume that there is a system dependent part of the framework, which is obviously different on Win7 and Win8. I built my application for version 4.0.

Comment: Surprisingly, I changed target framework version from 4.0 to 3.5 the bug disappeared.

Comment: Windows 8 has .NET 4.5 as the default, and it is an in-place replacement for .NET 4....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848079(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Try changing it to DelegateCommands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems, this is a breaking change in .Net Framework 4.5.
The issue is reported to Microsoft here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/751429/wpf-icommand-canexecutechanged-behaviour-change-in-net-4-5

Comment: This also hit me and it took quite some time until I finally figured out why my app wasn't working on systems with .net 4.5 installed. After lots of debugging and searching I found this which let me fix it. I was using the RelayCommand which used null as the sender.